# How to delete div class from php?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to delete div class="fep-avatar-more-60" from the plugin called Front-End-Pm.

I searched for that class on the plugin and here is what I found :

http://prntscr.com/16ma5t1

I tried to disable it via css,  but it still break the design,  is there anyway to remove that class via php ? or better is there anyway to remove it using the template in the child-theme ?

Thanks in advance

1- Class-fep-messages.php :

```html
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

//Message CLASS
class Fep_Messages {
    private static $instance;

    public static function init() {
        if ( ! self::$instance instanceof self ) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    function actions_filters() {
        add_action( 'fep_action_validate_form', array( $this, 'time_delay_check' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'fep_action_validate_form', array( $this, 'box_full_check' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'fep_posted_bulk_bulk_action', array( $this, 'bulk_action' ) );
    }

    function time_delay_check( $where, $errors ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $where, [ 'newmessage', 'shortcode-newmessage' ] ) ) {
            return;
        }
        $delay = absint( fep_get_option( 'time_delay', 5 ) );
        if ( fep_is_user_admin() || ! $delay ) {
            return;
        }
        $args = array(
            'mgs_type'      => 'message',
            'mgs_author'    => get_current_user_id(),
            'created_after' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "-{$delay} minutes" ) ),
            'fields'        => array( 'mgs_id' ),
            'per_page'      => 1,
        );
        if ( 'threaded' == fep_get_message_view() ) {
            $args['mgs_parent'] = 0;
        }
        if ( fep_get_messages( $args ) ) {
            $errors->add( 'time_delay', sprintf( __( 'Please wait at least %s between messages.', 'front-end-pm' ), sprintf( _n( '%s minute', '%s minutes', $delay, 'front-end-pm' ), number_format_i18n( $delay ) ) ) );
        }
    }

    function box_full_check( $where, $errors ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $where, [ 'newmessage', 'shortcode-newmessage' ] ) ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( ! $max = fep_get_current_user_max_message_number() ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( fep_get_user_message_count( 'total' ) >= $max ) {
            $errors->add( 'MgsBoxFull', __( 'Your message box is full. Please delete some messages.', 'front-end-pm' ) );
        }
    }

    function user_message_count( $value = 'all', $force = false, $user_id = false ) {
        if ( ! $user_id ) {
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        }
        if ( 'show-all' == $value ) {
            $value = 'total';
        }
        if ( ! $user_id ) {
            if ( 'all' == $value ) {
                return array();
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        $user_meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_fep_user_message_count', true );
        if ( false === $user_meta || $force || ! isset( $user_meta['total'] ) || ! isset( $user_meta['unread'] ) ) {
            $args = array(
                'mgs_type'      => 'message',
                'mgs_status'    => 'publish',
                'per_page'      => 0,
                'fields'        => 'COUNT(*)',
                'orderby'       => false,
            );
            if ( 'threaded' == fep_get_message_view() ) {
                $args['mgs_parent'] = 0;
            }
            $args = apply_filters( 'fep_message_count_query_args', $args, $user_id );
            
            $total_args = $args;
            $total_args['participant_query'][] = array(
                'mgs_participant' => $user_id,
                'mgs_deleted' => false,
            );
            
            $unread_args = $args;
            $unread_args['participant_query'][] = array(
                'mgs_participant' => $user_id,
                'mgs_parent_read' => false,
                'mgs_deleted' => false,
            );
            
            $user_meta = array(
                'total'     => fep_get_messages( $total_args ),
                'unread'    => fep_get_messages( $unread_args ),
            );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, '_fep_user_message_count', $user_meta );
        }
        if ( isset( $user_meta[$value] ) ) {
            return $user_meta[$value];
        }
        if ( 'all' == $value ) {
            return $user_meta;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    function user_messages( $action = 'messagebox', $user_id = false ) {
        if ( ! $user_id ) {
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        }
        $filter = ! empty( $_GET['fep-filter'] ) ? $_GET['fep-filter'] : '';
        $args = array(
            'mgs_type'      => 'message',
            'mgs_status'    => 'publish',
            'per_page'      => fep_get_option( 'messages_page', 15 ),
            'paged'         => ! empty( $_GET['feppage'] ) ? absint( $_GET['feppage'] ): 1,
            'check_more_row' => true,
            'count_total'    => false,
        );
        if ( 'threaded' == fep_get_message_view() ) {
            $args['mgs_parent'] = 0;
            $args['orderby'] = 'mgs_last_reply_time';
        } else {
            $args['orderby'] = 'mgs_created';
        }
        if ( ! empty( $_GET['fep-search'] ) ) {
            $args['s'] = $_GET['fep-search'];
        }
        switch ( $filter ) {
            case 'inbox':
                if ( 'threaded' == fep_get_message_view() ) {
                    $args['mgs_last_reply_by_not_in'] = [ $user_id ];
                } else {
                    $args['mgs_author_not_in'] = [ $user_id ];
                }
                $args['participant_query'][] = array(
                    'mgs_participant' => $user_id,
                    'mgs_deleted' => false,
                );
                break;
            case 'sent':
                if ( 'threaded' == fep_get_message_view() ) {
                    $args['mgs_last_reply_by'] = $user_id;
                } else {
                    $args['mgs_author'] = $user_id;
                }
                $args['participant_query'][] = array(
                    'mgs_participant' => $user_id,
                    'mgs_deleted' => false,
                );
                break;
            case 'archive':
                $args['participant_query'][] = array(
                    'mgs_participant' => $user_id,
                    'mgs_deleted' => false,
                    'mgs_archived' => true,
                );
                break;
            case 'read':
                $args['participant_query'][] = array(
                    'mgs_participant' => $user_id,
                    'mgs_deleted' => false,
                    'mgs_parent_read' => true,
                );
                break;
            case 'unread':
                $args['participant_query'][] = array(
                    'mgs_participant' => $user_id,
                    'mgs_deleted' => false,
                    'mgs_parent_read' => false,
                );
                break;
            default:
                $args['participant_query'][] = array(
                    'mgs_participant' => $user_id,
                    'mgs_deleted' => false,
                    'mgs_archived' => false,
                );
                $args = apply_filters( 'fep_message_query_args_' . $filter, $args, $user_id );
                break;
        }
        $args = apply_filters( 'fep_message_query_args', $args, $user_id );
        
        $query = new FEP_Message_Query( $args );
        
        return $query;
    }
    
    function get_message_with_replies( $id ) {
        $args = array(
            'mgs_type'      => 'message',
            'mgs_status'    => 'publish',
            'mgs_id'        => $id,
            'per_page'      => 0,
            'orderby'       =>'mgs_created',
            'order'         => 'ASC',
            'count_total'   => false,
        );
        if ( 'threaded' == fep_get_message_view() ) {
            $args['include_child'] = true;
        }
        $args = apply_filters( 'fep_filter_get_message_with_replies', $args );
        return new FEP_Message_Query( $args );
    }

    function bulk_action( $action, $ids = null ) {
        if ( null === $ids ) {
            $ids = ! empty( $_POST['fep-message-cb'] ) ? $_POST['fep-message-cb'] : array();
        }
        if ( ! $action || ! $ids || ! is_array( $ids ) ) {
            return;
        }
        $count = 0;
        foreach( $ids as $id ) {
            if ( $this->bulk_individual_action( $action, absint( $id ) ) ) {
                $count++;
            }
        }
        $message = '';
        if ( $count ) {
            delete_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_fep_user_message_count' );
            switch ( $action ) {
                case 'delete':
                    $message = sprintf( _n( '%s message successfully deleted.', '%s messages successfully deleted.', $count, 'front-end-pm' ), number_format_i18n( $count ) );
                    break;
                case 'mark-as-read':
                    $message = sprintf( _n( '%s message successfully marked as read.', '%s messages successfully marked as read.', $count, 'front-end-pm' ), number_format_i18n( $count ) );
                    break;
                case 'mark-as-unread':
                    $message = sprintf( _n( '%s message successfully marked as unread.', '%s messages successfully marked as unread.', $count, 'front-end-pm' ), number_format_i18n( $count ) );
                    break;
                case 'archive':
                    $message = sprintf( _n( '%s message successfully archived.', '%s messages successfully archived.', $count, 'front-end-pm' ), number_format_i18n( $count ) );
                    break;
                case 'restore':
                    $message = sprintf( _n( '%s message successfully restored.', '%s messages successfully restored.', $count, 'front-end-pm' ), number_format_i18n( $count ) );
                    break;
            }
            //$message = '<div class="fep-success">' . $message . '</div>';
        }
        $message = apply_filters( 'fep_message_bulk_action_message', $message, $count );
        if ( $message ) {
            fep_success()->add( 'success', $message );
        }
    }

    function bulk_individual_action( $action, $id ) {
        $return = false;
        
        switch ( $action ) {
            case 'delete':
                $return = fep_delete_message( $id );
                break;
            case 'mark-as-read':
                if ( fep_current_user_can( 'view_message', $id ) ) {
                    $return = fep_make_read( true, $id);
                }
                break;
            case 'mark-as-unread':
                if ( fep_current_user_can( 'view_message', $id ) ) {
                    $return = FEP_Participants::init()->unmark( $id, get_current_user_id(), [ 'parent_read' => true ] );
                }
                break;
            case 'archive':
                if ( fep_current_user_can( 'view_message', $id ) ) {
                    $return = FEP_Participants::init()->mark( $id, get_current_user_id(), ['archive' => true ] );
                }
                break;
            case 'restore':
                if ( fep_current_user_can( 'view_message', $id ) ) {
                    $return = FEP_Participants::init()->unmark( $id, get_current_user_id(), [ 'archive' => true ] );
                }
                break;
            default:
                $return = apply_filters( 'fep_message_bulk_individual_action', false, $action, $id, $id ); //second $id for back-word compatability
                break;
        }
        return $return;
    }

    function get_table_bulk_actions() {
        $filter = ! empty( $_GET['fep-filter'] ) ? $_GET['fep-filter'] : '';
        $actions = array(
            'delete'        => __( 'Delete', 'front-end-pm' ),
            'mark-as-read'  => __( 'Mark as read', 'front-end-pm' ),
            'mark-as-unread'=> __( 'Mark as unread', 'front-end-pm' ),
        );
        if ( 'archive' == $filter ) {
            $actions['restore'] = __( 'Restore', 'front-end-pm' );
        } else {
            $actions['archive'] = __( 'Archive', 'front-end-pm' );
        }
        return apply_filters( 'fep_message_table_bulk_actions', $actions );
    }

    function get_table_filters() {
        $filters = array(
            'show-all'  => __( 'Show all', 'front-end-pm' ),
            'inbox'     => __( 'Inbox', 'front-end-pm ' ),
            'sent'      => __( 'Sent', 'front-end-pm' ),
            'read'      => __( 'Read', 'front-end-pm' ),
            'unread'    => __( 'Unread', 'front-end-pm' ),
            'archive'   => __( 'Archive', 'front-end-pm' ),
        );
        return apply_filters( 'fep_message_table_filters', $filters );
    }

    function get_table_columns() {
        $columns = array(
            'fep-cb'    => __( 'Checkbox', 'front-end-pm' ),
            'avatar'    => __( 'Avatar', 'front-end-pm' ),
            'author'    => __( 'Author', 'front-end-pm' ),
            'title'     => __( 'Title', 'front-end-pm' ),
        );
        return apply_filters( 'fep_message_table_columns', $columns );
    }

    function get_column_content( $column ) {
        switch ( $column ) {
            case has_action( "fep_message_table_column_content_{$column}" ):
                do_action( "fep_message_table_column_content_{$column}" );
                break;
            case 'fep-cb':
                ?><input type="checkbox" class="fep-cb" name="fep-message-cb[]" value="<?php echo fep_get_the_id(); ?>" /><?php
                break;
            case 'avatar':
                if( $group = apply_filters( 'fep_is_group_message', false, fep_get_the_id() ) ){
                    ?><div class="fep-avatar-p fep-avatar-p-90"><?php
                    echo '<div class="fep-avatar-group-60" title="' . esc_attr( $group ) . '"></div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                } else {
                    $participants = fep_get_participants( fep_get_the_id() );
                    if ( apply_filters( 'fep_remove_own_avatar_from_messagebox', false )
                         && ( $key = array_search( get_current_user_id(), $participants ) ) !== false ) {
                        unset( $participants[$key] );
                    }
                    $count = 1;
                    ?>
                    <div class="fep-avatar-p <?php echo ( count( $participants ) > 2 ) ? 'fep-avatar-p-120': 'fep-avatar-p-90' ?>"><?php
                    foreach( $participants as $p ) {
                        if ( $count > 2 ) {
                            echo '<div class="fep-avatar-more-60" title="' . __( 'More users', 'front-end-pm' ) . '"></div>';
                            break;
                        } 
                        ?><div class="fep-avatar-<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( $p, 60, '', fep_user_name( $p ), array( 'extra_attr'=> 'title="' . esc_attr( fep_user_name( $p ) ) . '"' ) ); ?></div><?php
                        $count++;
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                break;
            case 'author':
                if( 'threaded' === fep_get_message_view() ){
                    ?><span class="fep-message-author"><?php echo fep_user_name( fep_get_message_field( 'mgs_last_reply_by' ) ); ?></span><span class="fep-message-date"><?php echo fep_get_the_date( 'mgs_last_reply_time' ); ?></span><?php
                } else {
                    ?><span class="fep-message-author"><?php echo fep_user_name( fep_get_message_field( 'mgs_author' ) ); ?></span><span class="fep-message-date"><?php echo fep_get_the_date( 'created' ); ?></span><?php
                }
                break;
            case 'title':
                if ( ! fep_is_read( true ) ) {
                    $span = '<span class="fep-unread-classp"><span class="fep-unread-class">' . __( 'Unread', 'front-end-pm' ) . '</span></span>';
                    $class = ' fep-strong';
                } else {
                    $span = '';
                    $class = '';
                } 
                ?><span class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><a href="<?php echo fep_query_url( 'viewmessage', [
                    'fep_id' => fep_get_the_id(),
                    'feppage' => isset( $_GET['feppage'] ) ? $_GET['feppage'] : 1,
                    'fep-filter' => isset( $_GET['fep-filter'] ) ? $_GET['fep-filter'] : '',
                    ] ); ?>"><?php echo fep_get_the_title(); ?></a></span><?php echo $span; ?>
                <div class="fep-message-excerpt">
                    <?php echo fep_get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div><?php
                break;
            default:
                do_action( 'fep_message_table_column_content', $column );
                break;
        }
    }
} //END CLASS

add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( Fep_Messages::init(), 'actions_filters' ) );
```

2 - View-message-heads.php :

```html
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

$messages_heads = Fep_Messages::init()->user_messages();

if ( $messages_heads->have_messages() ) {
    while ( $messages_heads->have_messages() ) {
        $messages_heads->the_message();
        ?>
        <div id="fep-message-head-<?php echo fep_get_the_id(); ?>" class="fep-message-head<?php echo ( isset( $_GET['fep_id'] ) && absint( $_GET['fep_id'] ) === fep_get_the_id() ) ? ' fep-message-head-active' : ''; ?>" data-fep_id="<?php echo fep_get_the_id(); ?>">
        <?php
        if ( $group = apply_filters( 'fep_is_group_message', false, fep_get_the_id() ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="fep-avatar-p fep-avatar-p-90">
                <div class="fep-avatar-group-60" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $group ); ?>"></div>
            </div>
            <?php
        } else {
            $participants = fep_get_participants( fep_get_the_id() );
            if ( apply_filters( 'fep_remove_own_avatar_from_messagebox', false )
                 && ( $key = array_search( get_current_user_id(), $participants ) ) !== false ) {
                unset( $participants[ $key ] );
            }
            $count = 1;
            ?>
            <div class="fep-avatar-p <?php echo ( count( $participants ) > 2 ) ? 'fep-avatar-p-120' : 'fep-avatar-p-90' ?>">
            <?php
            foreach ( $participants as $p ) {
                if ( $count > 2 ) {
                    echo '<div class="fep-avatar-more-60" title="' . __( 'More users', 'front-end-pm' ) . '"></div>';
                    break;
                }
                ?>
                <div class="fep-avatar-<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( $p, 60, '', fep_user_name( $p ), array( 'extra_attr' => 'title="' . esc_attr( fep_user_name( $p ) ) . '"' ) ); ?></div>
                <?php
                $count++;
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?></div><?php
    }
    echo fep_pagination_prev_next( $messages_heads->has_more_row );
} else {
    echo '<div class="fep-error">' . esc_html__( 'No messages found. Try different filter.', 'front-end-pm' ) . '</div>';
}
```

and here is the css file :

```css
/*The main wrapper*/
#fep-wrapper {
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

/*Header styling*/
#fep-header {
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    /* color: #000000; */
    width: 100%;
}

#fep-header strong {
    /* color: #333333; */
    font-size: 20px;
}

#fep-header .avatar {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/*Content styling*/
#fep-content {
    /* color: #000000; */
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

#fep-content p, #fep-content form {
    margin: 5px;
}

#fep-content hr {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#fep-content a {
    /* color: navy; */
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#fep-content .avatar {
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/*Footer styling*/
#fep-footer {
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    /* color: #333333; */
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#fep-footer a,
#fep-footer a:hover,
#fep-footer a:visited {
    /* color: #333333; */
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*Auto-suggest*/
#fep-result {
    background: #d3eef5;
    border: solid 1px #333333;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
}

#fep-result ul,
#fep-result li {
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#fep-result li {
    border-top: solid 1px #333333;
}

#fep-result li a {
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#fep-result li a:hover {
    background: #333333;
    color: white;
}

.fep-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.fep-table > div {
    display: table-row;
}

.fep-table > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.fep-table .fep-table-caption {
    display: table-caption;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.fep-action-table {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fep-action-table > div > div {
    width: 25%;
}

.fep-action-table select {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.fep-table .fep-column-avatar,
.fep-table .fep-column-fep-cb {
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.fep-table .fep-column-author,
.fep-table .fep-column-date {
    min-width: 150px;
}

.fep-table .fep-message-date {
    display:block;
    font-size: 70%;
}

.fep-table .fep-message-excerpt {
    opacity:0.3;
}

.fep-unread-classp {
    position:relative; 
}

.fep-unread-class {
    background-color: red; /* you could use a background image if you'd like as well */
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px gray;
    color: white;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 0 1px;
    position: absolute; /* This breaks the div from the normal HTML document. */
    top: -6px;
}

.fep-message-toggle-all {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fep-align-left {
    text-align: left;
}

.fep-align-right {
    text-align: right;
}

.fep-align-centre {
    text-align: center;
}

.fep-hd {
    display:none;
}

.fep-strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fep-pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.fep-pagination > li {
    display: inline;
}

.fep-pagination > li > a,
.fep-pagination > li > span {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    color: #337ab7;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fep-pagination > li:first-child > a,
.fep-pagination > li:first-child > span {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.fep-pagination > li:last-child > a,
.fep-pagination > li:last-child > span {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.fep-pagination > li > a:hover,
.fep-pagination > li > span:hover,
.fep-pagination > li > a:focus,
.fep-pagination >li > span:focus {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    color: #23527c;
}

.fep-pagination > .active > a,
.fep-pagination > .active > span,
.fep-pagination > .active > a:hover,
.fep-pagination > .active > span:hover,
.fep-pagination > .active > a:focus,
.fep-pagination > .active > span:focus {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #337ab7;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 2;
}

.fep-pagination > .disabled > span,
.fep-pagination > .disabled > span:hover,
.fep-pagination > .disabled > span:focus,
.fep-pagination > .disabled > a,
.fep-pagination > .disabled > a:hover,
.fep-pagination > .disabled > a:focus {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    color: #777777;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

#fep-message-top.fep-loading-gif,
.fep-loading-gif {
    background: url('../images/loading.gif') no-repeat right center;
    padding-right: 16px;
}

.fep-message .fep-message-title-heading,
.fep-per-message .fep-message-title {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* background-color: #f2f7fc; */
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.fep-message .fep-message-title-heading {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.fep-message .fep-message-title-heading .fep_block_unblock_user {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.fep-per-message .fep-message-title {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.fep-per-message {
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.fep-per-message .fep-message-title .date {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

.fep-per-message .fep-message-title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.fep-avatar-p {
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
}

.fep-avatar-p-120 {
    min-width: 120px;
}

.fep-avatar-p-90 {
    min-width: 90px;
}

.fep-avatar-p .fep-avatar-1,
.fep-avatar-p .fep-avatar-2,
.fep-avatar-more-60,
.fep-avatar-group-60 {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}

.fep-avatar-p .fep-avatar-2 {
    left: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.fep-avatar-more-60 {
    background: url('../images/avatar-more-60.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}

.fep-avatar-group-60 {
    background: url('../images/avatar-group-60.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}

.fep-avatar-p .fep-avatar-more-60 {
    left: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.fep-attachments {
    border-top:1px solid #e7e7e7;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.fep-attachments-heading {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fep-attachment-icon {
    background: transparent url('../images/attachment-icons.png') no-repeat;
    margin-right: 4px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-default {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-generic {
    background-position: 0 -16px;
}
/* need in php */
.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-code {
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-xml {
    background-position: 0 -48px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-excel {
    background-position: 0 -64px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-word {
    background-position: 0 -80px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-image {
    background-position: 0 -96px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-psd {
    background-position: 0 -112px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-ai {
    background-position: 0 -128px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-archive {
    background-position: 0 -144px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-text {
    background-position: 0 -160px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-powerpoint {
    background-position: 0 -176px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-pdf {
    background-position: 0 -192px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-html {
    background-position: 0 -208px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-video {
    background-position: 0 -224px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-documents {
    background-position: 0 -240px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-audio {
    background-position: 0 -256px;
}

.fep-attachment-icon.fep-attachment-icon-icon {
    background-position: 0 -272px;
}

#fep-menu-toggle-button {
    display: none;
}
#fep-menu-toggle-button:after {
    content: '+';
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#fep-menu-toggle-button.fep-menu-toggle-expanded:after {
    content: '-';
}

.fep-loader {
    cursor: wait;
    background:#ffffff url('../images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity: 0.75;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: none;
}

#fep-content-single {
    display: flex;
}
#fep-content-single #fep-content-single-sidebar {
    padding: 5px;
    flex: 20%;
    min-width: 150px;
}
#fep-content-single #fep-content-single-main {
    width: 100%;
}
.fep-message-head {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fep-filter-heads-div {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#fep-content-single-heads .fep-message-head-active {
    border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 0px;
}

#fep-content-single-heads .fep-error {
    background-color: #ffebe8;
    border-color: #c00;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .fep-table .fep-column-avatar {
        display: none;
    }

    .fep-action-table,
    .fep-action-table > div,
    .fep-action-table > div > div {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .fep-action-table > div > div {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #fep-menu .fep-button,
    .fep-button,
    .fep-button-active {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .fep-menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    #fep-menu-toggle-button {
        display: block;
    }
    #fep-content-single #fep-content-single-sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .fep-table .fep-message-excerpt {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify the reason why this question was closed, it's because it contains ***way*** too much code for a simple problem. You need to create a [MCVE] (emphasis on *minimal* here) that reproduces your problem. If you are still having this problem and need an answer, please use the [edit] link to update your question, following the above-linked guidance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JS code to do this.
Use this code to remove an HTML tag class with JS:

```
<script>
      var element = document.getElementById(".fep-avatar-more-60");
      element.classList.remove("fep-avatar-more-60");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Jquery to remove the class.

There are few things that we should keep in mind.

1. There can be multiple instance of `.fep-avatar-more-60` class.
2. We get all the instance of that class and use `.each()` to loop around it.
3. Once that is done, use `.removeClass()` to remove the said class.

```js
$(function() {
  var fepAvatars = $('.fep-avatar-more-60');
  fepAvatars.each(function( key, fepAvatar ) {
    fepAvatars.removeClass("fep-avatar-more-60");
  });
});
```

```css
.fep-avatar-more-60 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="fep-avatar-more-60">
  Something
</span>
adadasd
<span class="fep-avatar-more-60">
  Other thing
</span>
```

### Explanation

This particular example shows two instance of the class. Both are marked red using the class.But with query the classes are removed and the color red is not set. You can test by commenting out the Jquery to see indeed the text are red.

So to summarize. Add this Jquery on the page where you want the class to be removed

```
$(function() {
  var fepAvatars = $('.fep-avatar-more-60');
  fepAvatars.each(function( key, fepAvatar ) {
    fepAvatars.removeClass("fep-avatar-more-60");
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello, why should load a full library while js can handle it quiet easily : `for (let e of document.querySelectorAll(".fep-avatar-more-60")) { e.classList.remove("fep-avatar-more-60"); }` this is one of the syntax that can be used and set on a single line ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, well the author is using wordpress and as Jquery is a dependency for wordpress he/she is definetly loading JQuery either way, so it makes sense to use Jquery as the page will not be loading any extra dependency. This is the SVN of the plugin author is using : https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/front-end-pm/branches/5.1/assets/js/. You can see Jquery being used. But I do agree that vanilla JS should also be correct.